# What is the cause of this error: Error: EACCES, permission denied

Tags: files, permissions, node.js

I have two three users:

db, nr, ba

All three are members of the group dbp

Node.js is installed in /usr/bin

If I run the command :

```
/usr/bin/node /home/db/dbb/m/i.js
```

Then it works fine when I run it as user "ba".
But if I run it as "nr", then it crashes with the error:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied './manifest.json'
```

dbb has permissions: `drwxr-s--- db dbp`
manifest.json is a file located in the same folder as i.js
The app seems to start and executes until it tries to read manifest.json, at which point it crashes.

EDIT: umask is 027

EDIT: The output of `stat ./manifest.json` is:

```
 File: `manifest.json'
  Size: 251         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca00h/51712d    Inode: 2598        Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/db)   Gid: ( 1001/db)
Access: 2014-11-18 18:03:48.297158000 +0000
Modify: 2014-11-18 18:03:37.000000000 +0000
Change: 2014-11-18 18:03:48.298380902 +0000
 Birth: -
```

EDIT: I deleted the user account db, as well as the group dbp. I set the umask to 002. I then recreated only the user account db, and tried to run the command `/usr/bin/node /home/db/dbb/m/i.js` as db, but had the same error.

This time when I did `stat manifest.json`, I got the same output:

```
File: `manifest.json'
  Size: 251         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca00h/51712d    Inode: 2368        Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/db)   Gid: ( 1001/db)
Access: 2014-11-18 19:08:35.709657000 +0000
Modify: 2014-11-18 18:03:37.000000000 +0000
Change: 2014-11-18 19:08:35.708011027 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: How about the output of `stat manifest.json`?  Note you can format output and commands by indenting four spaces or enclosing in backticks (`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is owned by user `db` and group `db`:

```
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/db)   Gid: ( 1001/db)
```

But is world readable (444).  The directory hierarchy it is in is not, but it should be readable by group `dbp`, **unless** `/home/db` has non-default permissions.  This may be the case since your umask (027) is stricter than normal (002).

Otherwise, it would seem the EACCES error likely occurred because the process tried to open the file for *writing.*

Comment: I tried running as db, after deleting the user accounts, group and recreating them. I also set the umask to 002, and had the same problem. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Sure.  `su` to whichever user you want to run node as and try to open that file for reading.  If all of them can, then perhaps node is trying to execute or write to it.  You might also want to make sure it's the same `manifest.json` that's at issue.

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal and type the following Command :

```
sudo chown -R $user:$group ./manifest.json
```